# Sorting a Vector without losing it's pointer (on Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, vector, indexing

I have a simple 1x10 vector with percentage values like this:

```
[0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0 0 0.1 0 0 0.1].
```

I want to sort them in a descending order without losing track if their respective indexes. I need something like this for example:

```
0.4  4
0.2  2
0.2  3
0.1  7
0.1  10
0    1
0    5
0    6
0    8
0    9
```

Thanks for your help, bear with me as I am new to matlab and there so many built-in functions!!

Comment: `[new,idx] = sort(old)` will return the sorted indecies in `idx`.

Comment: @eigenchris Cheers, going to try it.

Comment: Also, if you want descending order you'll have to use `sort(old,'descend')`.

Comment: @eigenchris Make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
[sorted_vector,idx] = sort(old_vector,'descend');
```

`idx` will return the indeces of the sorted vector elements.

`'descend'` will sort the vector in descending order.